# How create a file and put my data in there?

Tags: javascript, sdp

If I have a string bellow:

```
const inputString = 
"v=0
o=- 1443716955 1443716955 IN IP4 10.20.130.110
m=video 20000 RTP/AVP 96 // <== this line 
c=IN IP4 239.0.1.2/64
a=source-filter: incl IN IP4 239.0.1.2 192.168.0.1
a=rtpmap:96 raw/90000
a=mid:primary
m=video 20000 RTP/AVP 96 // <== this line 
c=IN IP4 239.0.1.3/64
a=source-filter: incl IN IP4 239.0.1.3 192.168.0.1";
```

And want to save it like SDP file, How is it possible!

Comment: Is the string already formatted and you just want to save it to a file?

Comment: Are you using node? Sending it to a server? Or just want to download?

Comment: Yes,exactly  @Aplet123

Comment: I using node, and want to create file for upload

Comment: Then you can simply do `const fs = require("fs"); fs.writeFileSync("data.sdp", inputString);`